# Add my REST API written by NodeJS to the Kubernetes as custom resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

I've read about Kubernetes custom resources and have seen controllers in go language.
But I can't understand how i can connect the CR to my App deployment.

I've written a NodeJS/Express REST API, the problem is how I can make it a part of Kubernetes api endpoints?

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?  Say I write a YAML file that uses the custom resource type and `kubectl apply` it; how does that interact with the REST service you've written?

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes and how i can connect it to my REST service, e.g ```kubectl get ladies``` then it connect to my REST end point and respond my JSON.

Comment: or ```kubectl create ladywatcher -n lady1``` then create a custom prometheus exporter for ```lady1``` namespace. something like that.

Comment: `kubectl get ...` will always return an object from the Kubernetes API server.  It sounds like you might need to write a [controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/) that reads the custom resource, makes the HTTP call, and writes the response into some Kubernetes object (could be the same one or a new managed object).

Comment: Yes and I can't find out a sample controller structure in JS, there's only for GoLang or JAVA.

Comment: @DavidMaze it seems this is what I need. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dot-i/k8s-operator